# Cannot redeclare create_post_type() (previously declared

Tags: php, wordpress

Running 2 very similar plugins in one wp install. And when trying to activate a new one, I'm getting "Cannot redeclare previously declared" error. Error refers to one of the similar plugins. But post types are actually different (code follows). Server cache cleared.

New post type

```
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'Related',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name'               => 'Related',
        'singular_name'      => 'Related Unit',
        'menu_name'          => 'Related Units',
        'name_admin_bar'     => 'Related Unit',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Unit',
        'new_item'           => 'New Unit',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Unit',
        'view_item'          => 'View Unit',
        'all_items'          => 'All Units',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Units',
        'parent_item_colon'  => 'Parent Units:',
        'not_found'          => 'No units found.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No units found in Trash.'
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => true,
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'supports' => array( 
        'title', 
        'revisions'
    ),
    )
  );
  register_taxonomy("RelatedPlacements", array("Related"), array(
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "label" => "Related Placements",
    "singular_label" => "Related Placement",
    "rewrite" => true
    ));
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

And the one error is referring to

```
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'Ads',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name'               => 'Ads',
        'singular_name'      => 'Ad',
        'menu_name'          => 'Ads',
        'name_admin_bar'     => 'Ad',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Ad',
        'new_item'           => 'New Ad',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Ad',
        'view_item'          => 'View Ad',
        'all_items'          => 'All Ads',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Ads',
        'parent_item_colon'  => 'Parent Ads:',
        'not_found'          => 'No ads found.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No ads found in Trash.'
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => true,
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'supports' => array( 
        'title', 
        'revisions'
    ),
    )
  );
  register_taxonomy("Placements", array("ads"), array(
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "label" => "Placements",
    "singular_label" => "Placement",
    "rewrite" => true
    ));
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

I just don't see how are these the same

Comment: Use [PHP namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define two functions with the same name in PHP.  Change one of the function names:

```
function create_related_post_type() {
   ...
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_related_post_type' );
```

Because of Wordpress's procedural code base and large potential of plugin conflicts, it's usually recommended to prefix your functions with a unique name, like `pluginname_create_post_type`.

Comment: that did it. Thank you! Gotta wait 7 mins to accept.